# Point Grey BlackFly GigE Vision Camera Remote Access on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, camera, network-camera

Let me preface this by saying that I'm not sure SuperUser is the correct place to ask this question, so if it's not, please advise and I'll move as appropriate.

I'm trying to use a Point Grey BlackFly GigE Vision camera while SSH-ing into a development machine remotely, so the solution I'm currently trying is to connect to the Internet over the hardware ethernet port with a static IP address, and connect to the camera over a USB ethernet adapter. This doesn't seem to be working, and my suspicion is that it's because the FlyCapture software looks only at some specific ethernet ports (the hardware ones) and not at the USB ethernet port.

As I said, I'm on Arch, so it's not a supported distribution. I used `debtap` to convert the debian packages to Arch packages, and they all installed correctly (except the update package, but it didn't seem necessary). I'm running the `GigEGrabEx` C++ example, and the output is similar to the output of all the Python libraries I initially tried: "No suitable GigE cameras found". I would assume a failed/improper install of any packages would have led to a different error, but I can't be certain. I'll be trying the `flycap` software when in-person and on a GUI interface, but I'd rather solve this beforehand if possible, as even if that works/doesn't work, it won't really change my underlying issue, as I need a Python interface (or at least a C++ interface I can wrap in Python).

Does anyone see any obvious potential solutions to my problem? If I don't figure this out in the next day or two, I'll probably just try it on ubuntu, but I'd much rather have a solution on Arch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the network interface not being set up.

First, one must re-enable IPv4 DHCP leases in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` (and maybe also disable IPv6 DHCP routing, as I also did that).

```
# /etc/dhcpcd.conf

# comment this line out
#noipv4ll

# maybe add this line, probably not necessary
noipv6rs
```

Next, get a DHCP lease for the camera.
`sudo dhcpcd [your-camera's-ethernet-interface, e.g. eth1]`

Now it should be all good to go!